# Why refer to elements in this weird way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, terminology

Often while reading in Jacobson's Basic Algebra textbook, I find him referring to elements of a set in a particular, weird way.

Instead of saying for example "let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be elements of $S$", he says let $i \mapsto x_i$ be a map of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ into $S$.

Why does he do this? Is it just for rigour purposes?

Added: here is a concrete one.

> For any ring $R$ and any positive integer $r$ there exists a ring $R[x_1,\ldots,x_r]$ with the following "universal" property. If $S$ is any ring and $\eta$ is a homomorphism of $R$ into $S$ and $i\mapsto u_i$ is a map of $\{1,\ldots,r\}$ into $S$, then there exists a unique extension of $\eta$ to a homomorphism of $R[x_1,\ldots,x_r]$ into $S$ sending $x_i$ to $u_i$, $1\le i \le r$.

Another one is on page $69$ (first volume) when talking about free groups.

Comment: Without context, it is impossible to answer. He might use this special form for some arguments later.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt I added context.

Comment: The additional information is that in that way the elements of $S$ are "ordered".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA in what sense?

Comment: In the sense: 1st element, 2nd element,...

Comment: See page 124; the proof is by *induction* on $r$ in $R[x_1, \ldots, x_r]$; induction needs numbers: $1,2,\ldots$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I really don't see the significance of this. To me this is exactly the same as "let $x_1,\ldots,x_r$ be elements of $S$".

Comment: Note that he does not assume the map $i \mapsto u_i$ to be injective, so we could have $u_i = u_j$ for $i \neq j$, something that is not possible in a set.

Comment: @DirkLiebhold so when we say "let $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in S$", we are saying "let $\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\} \subset S$"?

Comment: It might depend, some might implicitly assume the $x_i$ to be different in this case, others might not. This issue is resolved by Jacobson by using functions: If he wants the function to be injective, he can say so, thus it is always clear what he's talking about. In the above example, the theorem stays true even if the map is not injective.

Comment: This is indeed a weird way to write things like this, but it might be to introduce a commutative diagram. Your examples express indeed some universal properties and universal properties are often represented with a commutative diagram. In that case, one really needs maps instead of elements.

Comment: @Cauchy No, not "let $\{u_1,\ldots u_n\}\subset S$ " because that still doesn't permit repetitions. You could say "Let $\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\}$ be a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) of elements of $S$" to try to solve this, but then there isn't an extension corresponding to the *multiset* because the order in which the elements are mapped matters. It is very nice and natural to say "this map uniquely gives rise to this extension map,"  and this direction you're going by trying to translate to sets does not suffice for any of that.

Comment: Many objects in algebra can be characterized by *universal mapping properties*, which are naturally expressed in purely map-theoretic language (this will be clearer if you study universal algebra and category theory). Here the idea is that $R[x_1,\cdots, x_n]$ is a commutative ring obtained by adjoining a sequence of $n$ generic elements ("indeterminates") in the most general (universal) way possible (in particular the $x_i$ are "algebraically independent" over $R$, i.e. satisfy no polynomial equations over $R).\,$

Comment: Such universality ends up being  equivalent to saying that any other such adjunction to $R$ (or an image $S)$ is an image of the universal adjunction $\,R[X] = R[x_1,\cdots, x_n],\,$ which may be expressed in said map-theoretic language. This means that any equation that holds true in $R[X] = R[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ maps to a true equation in any image of $R$ when the  $x_i$ are evaluated in the image. So we can view $\,R[X]\,$ the universal identities of $R$, i.e. those true in every $R$-algebra,  e.g. $\,x_1^2-x_2^2 = (x_1 - x_2)(x_1+ x_2),\,$ binomial  theorem, cyclotomic factorizations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the *uniqueness* of the extension, as claimed in the book. If you didn't have a map $i\mapsto u_i$ to begin with, you couldn't make such a claim.  More importantly, notice that the map $i\mapsto u_i$ is not required to be injective. The uniqueness claim remains true.

Comment: I still don't see what difference the map thing makes. Why is uniqueness affected if we just say "let $x_1,\ldots, x_r\in S$"? Unless what you are referring to is just the remark Dirk already gave.

Comment: If you change the order, the extended map changes as well.  Again, you don't need to have $r$ distinct members of $S$ either.

Comment: I really don't think uniqueness has to do with anything here. I think it is just what Dirk mentioned in the comments (and what you subsequently mentioned in your answer).

Comment: @MikhailKatz I know the direction you're headed in is the right one... but the answer could be improved by being a bit more explicit! Probably even one example would suffice to show how order and repetition are both handled by the map scheme Jacobson gave.

Comment: Hi @rschwieb, thanks.  I think the OP seems in command of the material.